# How to send NSURL request containig @ in the username

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

How can i send a url request containing a `@` character in the username ?
Currently my url request code looks as follows :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://user@exam.com:pwd@example.com"]];
```

The above code is fetching data from site exam.com instead of example.com

**How can i fetch data from example.com with user@exam.com as username name and pwd as password ?**

I tried escape sequences like `\` for escaping the `@` character but still its not working.

Comment: Have you tried to url encode the first @ to %40?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always encode your parameter before making a NSURL from them

```
 NSString * encodedUsername = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unencodedUsername,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode a string before using it to generate a url like below :

```
NSString * encodedString = [q stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```